# The pound is not a finish

Tags: letters

Starting with `The pound is not a finish`, apply all of the following modifications in the correct order to reveal a **popular scientific fact**:

- Remove one word.
- Remove one letter from one word.
- Change one letter for another letter.
- Replace one word with an antonym of itself.
- Remove two letters from one word.

Comment: This just makes me think of the proverbial *pound of flesh*.

Comment: −1 for revisions 3 and 5.  “rearrange and do” is so obfuscated as to be inscrutable.

Comment: @PeregrineRook see edit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answer:

> The sun is a star

Steps:

> The pound is not a finish

Replace one word with an antonym of itself.

> The pound is not a start

Remove one letter from one word.

> The pound is not a star

Remove one word.

> The pound is a star

Change one letter for another letter.

> The sound is a star

Remove two letters from one word.

> The sun is a star

How I got there:

> The antonym is obviously the critical step.  If it had to be applied after some of the other steps, the puzzle would have been more difficult.  But giving it a shot on the initial sentence, "finish" -> "start" was the obvious candidate, then "scientific fact" suggests "star", making the rest easy.

Comment: Just saw *in no particular order* Nice! +1

Answer (score 5):

This is likely to be *too broad*.

the pound is not a finish

> `Remove one word.`
>  The pound is not <s>a</s> finish.
>  `Remove one letter from one word.`
>  The po<s>u</s>nd is not finish.
>  `Replace one word with an antonym of itself.`
>  The pond is not *start*.
>  `Remove two letters from one word.`
>  The pond is not s<s>ta</s>rt.
>  `Change one letter for another letter.`
>  The pond is not *a*rt.

With nothing particularly confining what sort of fact we're supposed to come up with out of this, I submit my finding as a valid fact that can be derived from applying your instructions to your starting phrase.

Comment: The pond *could be* art

Comment: Anything *could be* art :)

Comment: I knew a guy named Art.

Comment: I don't believe this to be a broad question. I rephrased the requirement once you posted your answer, but it seems people still agree with you that it's too broad, without giving feedback on my change.

Comment: It looks like most if not all the downvotes and alternate answers came before the question revision. (Note that it's usually a good idea to mention that the question changed, if and when those changes invalidate answers already given, so later readers don't think those answers are disregarding parts of the question and downvote answers that were perfectly valid when posted)  maybe with the question's edits people will revisit their votes - but don't count on it.

Answer (score 3):

Remove one word.

> the pound is a finish

Remove one letter from one word.

> the pond is a finish

Change one letter for another letter.

> the bond is a finish

Replace one word with an antonym of itself.

> the bond is a start

Remove two letters from one word

> **the bond is a art** (incorrect grammar) or **the bond is a tar** or **The On is a start.** (Referring to electric button) or **H bond is a start** (Related to Hydrogen bonding which starts almost all the bondings - Chemistry)

Comment: "H bond is a start" is my favorite answer

Comment: These aren't *popular*