# Elephants always get four mice

Tags: wordplay, letters

Starting with `Elephants always get four mice`, do all the following in the correct order to reveal **a popular phrase**:

- Replace one word with its antonym
- Delete one space
- Remove one word
- Remove one letter from one word
- Move one word's position

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is

> **Elephants never forget.**

Starting with *Elephants always get four mice*, we perform the following steps in order:

- Replace one word with its antonym

  > *Elephants never get four mice*
- Move one word's position

  > *Elephants never four get mice*
- Delete one space

  > *Elephants never fourget mice*
- Remove one word

  > *Elephants never fourget*
- Remove one letter from one word

  > *Elephants never forget*

Comment: I think it's safe to say I should've made this question harder :)

Comment: @rybo111 One way to make it harder would have been to make the choice less obvious. Only one word in the original sentence *has* an antonym, for instance; that narrows down the possibilities a lot.

Comment: Technically the antonym could be applied to another word, but I see your point - the antonym is applied at the start, which makes it obvious. I'd like to make these harder but not impossible, so feedback is appreciated.

Comment: @rybo111 Let's see how this one fares: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/49236/5373 :-)

Comment: This was my first one in case you missed it - http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49144/the-pound-is-not-a-finish

Comment: @rybo111 Well, we both hit HNQ out of these questions!