# Yes, your fat ma is hers

Tags: wordplay, letters, quote

<sup>Inspired by [Elephants always get four mice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/49234/5373).</sup>

---

Start with the phrase `Yes, your fat ma is hers` and perform the following steps, in some order, to find a **famous quote**:

- Rearrange the words.
- Remove a single letter from one word.
- Reverse one word.
- Remove one space.
- Replace one word by its antonym.
- Remove a single letter from one word.

Comment: So, removing a single letter would be done twice?

Comment: @Sid Yes (need more chars)

Comment: Does the comma remain?

Comment: @rybo111 It might or might not. The important thing is the words, not the punctuation.

Comment: What did you say about my fat ma?

Comment: @Richard That [when she hits Warp 1, she bounces](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138999/what-insults-did-the-vulcan-children-use-to-try-to-goad-spock#comment352211_138999).

Comment: @randal'thor I made [another](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49742/thaw-sues-cold-dog)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The answer is:

> No, I am your father.

Steps:

> Starting Phrase - Yes, your fat ma is hers.
>  First, take an antonym - No, your fat ma is hers.
>  Second, reverse - No, your fat am is hers.
>  Then, remove one letter - No, Your fat am I hers
>  Then, rearrange - No, I am your fat hers
>  Remove the last letter of "hers" - No, I am your fat her
>  Finally, remove one space - **No, I am your father**

This quote is from:

> *Star Wars - The Empire Strikes Back*

Comment: Conclusively proving that the quote is *not* 'Luke, I am your father'. (how does Rand know this? He's never watched SW.)

Comment: @Mithrandir Perhaps unfortunately, I've spent enough time on a certain sci-fi website to have picked up a lot of info like this by osmosis :-) Also, spoilers!