# Thaw Sue's cold dog

Tags: wordplay, letters, quote

Start with the phrase `Thaw Sue's cold dog` and perform the following steps in some order to find **a famous question**:

- Add one letter
- Add one letter
- Change one letter
- Rearrange the letters of one word
- Rearrange the letters of one word
- Rearrange the words
- Remove one letter

*Note: You can ignore punctuation, and add/remove punctuation as required,
at any point.  Thus, `Sue’s` is one word.*

Comment: If we publicise this question enough, I've got an answer that's more efficient than any currently posted. (I am going by the definition of "famous question" used in the Gold Badge).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I will pretend to understand what you mean

Comment: @wizzwizz4 just worked out what you mean (took me a while)

Comment: @wizzwizz4:  Ha ha!  I get it.

Comment: Who Let The Dogs Out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Start with the phrase

> Thaw Sue’s cold dog

and perform the following steps:

Add one letter:

> Thaw Sue’s co**u**ld dog

Add one letter

> Thaw **j**Sue’s could dog

Change one letter

> Thaw jSue’s **w**ould dog

Rearrange the letters of one word

> *What* jSue’s would dog

Rearrange the letters of one word

> What *Jesu’s* would dog
> *Note: adding/removing punctuation is not included in the steps.* →
> What Jesus would dog?

Rearrange the words

> What would Jesus dog?

Remove one letter

> What would Jesus *do*?

Comment: Spoiler Warning:  I saw the first word almost immediately, but I expected that the fourth word would be rearranged (spelled backwards), and so I spun my wheels for a few minutes trying to get “hath wrought” out of the other two words.  (And, in fact, you can also get “hath” from “thaw”.)    :-)    ⁠

Comment: It is funny that I tried God in my answer, but the correct answer is not God, it is Jesus.

Comment: @VictorStafusa I noticed that, too. Spooky!

Comment: OK, so we’re not even trying to keep the words that are in the answer hidden any more?  (I guess it’s not really necessary, in the comments.)  As long as the answer contains a word that is one letter different from “God”, it’s hard to avoid having a word in the puzzle that’s equally close to “God”.  But you could have avoided making it a simple permutation by making the puzzle “Thaw Sue’s cold cod” (a frozen fish!), “Thaw Sue’s cold doe”, “Thaw old cold Seuss”, “Sue’s bold math duo” or “Chat: Sue’s cold?  Nod.”    :-)    ⁠

Answer (score 7):

Original:

> Thaw Sue's cold dog

Add one letter:

> Thaw Sue's could dog

Change one letter:

> Thow Sue's could dog

Rearrange the letters of one word

> Thow Sue's could God

Rearrange the letters of one word

> Thow uses could God

Rearrange the words

> Thow could God uses?

Remove one letter

> How could God uses?

Remove one letter

> How could God use?

Comment: I'm finding that Thaw is an anagram of what

Comment: Is that really a famous question?

Comment: Apologies, I made an error in the question. Now fixed.

Comment: Three of you were put to good use :)